# Is there a way to create a template for methods in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, c#-4.0, methods

We have a client that has us do some custom error catching and custom commenting that they prefer in a c# project.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to have VS 2010 template methods so as I create a new one it would auto-format it into a common layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to have the code snippets used when using the "generate from usage" approach?

Comment: @Chris: I was wrong; it is possible.  Edit C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodStub.snippet